# C# accessing memory map file

Tags: c#, memory

Looking for code samples to access a memory map file in C#

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like C# 4.0 will have MemoryMappedFile support in the library

Comment: It's `System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile`.

Answer (score 11):

You can take a look at [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/MemoryMappedGenericArray.aspx) which shows a simple array over MMF implementation using [Winterdom's FileMap library](http://www.winterdom.com/dev/dotnet/index.html) - basically a wrapper around the Win32 APIs for memory mapped files.

Caveat emptor: 1) I have not used FileMap, so I can't vouch for it; 2) FileMap is under LGPL, if the licensing terms are of any concer of you.

You can also search on http://pinvoke.net for the P/Invoke definitions of the corresponding Win32 APIs and roll your own implementation.

Answer (score 1):

http://1code.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IRPC

Search with

```
CSFileMappingClient
CSFileMappingServer
```