# Removing a line in a text file, by specifying an item from a ListBox

Tags: c#, .net

I have a situation where I would like to be able to select a value / row in a ListBox, and have this selected value removed from a text file, e.g. test.txt. How could this be done?

Comment: Do you fill each line into the ListBox?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficient way to delete a line from a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532217/efficient-way-to-delete-a-line-from-a-text-file)

Comment: That question is very similar to your, meanwhile answer proposed proposes much more efficient solution that @Magnus's one, however it's pretty ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text file is small your can read it all into memory in replace the string.

```
var str = File.ReadAllText("c:\\test.txt");
File.WriteAllText("c:\\test.txt", str.Replace(strToRemove, ""));
```

Comment: @Magnus Hi, could you elaborate a little, on how abouts this would be done with a ListBox

Comment: `strToRemove` would be the selected value of the Listbox

Comment: @Magnus Cheers, got it now :)

Comment: Very poor answer, as that'll replace all lines that look like it. If you don't have any duplicate lines, then it's fine, but if multiple lines look alike, you're removing them all.

Comment: @MindWorX I dont think so, he wants to have "this selected value removed from a text file" if that value appears many times, than of course he would want to remove all of them.

Comment: @Magnus He says he's filling the ListBox with lines from the document, which means he's effectively trying to remove a selected line. I guess the question is too vague to answer properly.

Comment: @MindWorX So what if he does. If two lines are the same, who are you to say that he doesn't want to delete both of them? Especially after accepting the answer.

Comment: @Magnus Like I said, the answer is too vague/poorly written to answer properly, which is probably why it's also being down voted by people.

Answer (score 0):

first you get the selected value text from the `listbox` then

Read the whole file into `memory` (e.g.
   with `File.ReadAllLines`) Remove the
   offending line based on the value of `listbox` (in this case it's
   probably easiest to convert the
   string array into a `List<string>` then
   remove the line) Write all the rest
   of the lines back (e.g. with
   `File.WriteAllLines`) - potentially
   convert the `List<string>` into a
   string array again using `ToArray` That
   means you have to know that you've
   got enough memory though.