# Can I create a virtual disk in memory programatically?

Tags: c#, .net, virtual-disk

For performance purposes I want to write to memory, where an external application can read. I can't link both applications together, so I think the only way is by writing a file. But writing it to a physical disk isn't fast enough. I want to mount a virtual partition so any application can access it. How to do it?

Comment: Check [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/ShowMessages.aspx?ThreadID=55821) out.

Comment: DevCon is not redistributable. It is provided for use as a debugging and development tool.

Comment: Source of above statement: http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B311272&x=12&y=11

Comment: My application will not be redistributed

Comment: Even if it does, I can ask that people download and install it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a named pipe to transfer the data between applications.

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to go as far as creating a virtual disk to share memory between processes on Windows - you can create a shared memory block, and multiple processes can then access that memory.

See this MSDN article: [Creating Named Shared Memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366551(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I have seen some commersial avaliable ramdisk implementation for .net but I cant seem to find it right now.

Another option might be: [C# accessing memory map file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216083/csharp-accessing-memory-map-file)

Answer (score 1):

I wish you can use .NET 4.0 :)

.NET 4.0 introduces memory mapped file.

Gunnar Peipman blogged nicely in the following link: [.Net Framework 4.0: Using memory mapped files](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/06/21/net-framework-4-0-using-memory-mapped-files.aspx)

In his blog, "*Memory mapped files are useful when you need to do in-memory data manipulation and your data structures are large. For large in-memory data the performance of memory mapped file is the best. It is much faster than MemoryStream. And like files on hard disc, **memory mapped files can be shared between different programs**."*

His blog also contains the sample code as well.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that only .NET applications can access such files.